# "Describe the topology that {(x,0)∈ℝ^2|x∈ℝ} inherits as a subspace of ℝ^2 with the standard topology"

Tags: general-topology

This is a problem from “Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied” by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa.

PROBLEM

"Let X = {(x, 0) ∈ ℝ^2 | x ∈ ℝ}, the x-axis in the plane. Describe the topology that X inherits as a subspace of ℝ^2 with the standard topology."

THOUGHTS

The standard topology on ℝ^2 is generated by the collection of open balls.

X = {(x, 0) ∈ ℝ^2 | x ∈ ℝ} is every real number point on the x-axis in R^2.

If we let X inherit a subspace of ℝ^2, does it become the standard topology on ℝ? My thinking is that every real number point is open in R^2. If we intersect that with X, we get all the open intervals in ℝ.

If that's even correct, how can I phrase it better?

As always, I appreciate any help.

Comment: 'Every real number point is open in $\mathbb R^{2}$'? What makes you think so?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I thought that, similar to how ℝ contains all real numbers, ℝ^2 contains all real points. I guess I should say all real 2-tuples?

Comment: The question was: what makes you think that every real number point is open in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos well we're talking about the standard topology on ℝ^2 which is generated by the collection of all open balls. If we take the union of all open balls I thought we get all (x, y) points in ℝ^2... but I guess we don't get all open points, we get all open balls... I'm still trying to understand it.

Comment: *No* set consisting of a single point is open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos what's a good way to phrase it? Should I say 2-tuples?

Comment: To phrase *what*? I don't know what you are trying to express.

Comment: Similar to how the standard topology on ℝ contains all real numbers, the standard topology on ℝ^2 contains all _____

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts. This is your tenth one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inherited topology is generated by the intersection of the open balls with the real line. 
Since the intersections are open intervals the inherited topology is the standard topology of the real line.